# Ввод из файла динамического массива в функции

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++

После ввода из файла выводит непонятные символы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void inputStudfile(student *x, int &k)
{
    ifstream fin;
    char file[L], iniz[4];
    student t;
    cout << "Введите имя файла с необходимым списком:";
    cin >> file;
    fin.open(file);
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Файл *" << file << "* не создан ";
        getch();
        return;
    }
    k = 0;
    while (1) {
        fin >> t.name >> iniz >> t.dr.a >> t.dr.b >> t.dr.c;
        strcat(t.name, " ");
        strcat(t.name, iniz);
        if (fin.fail()) {
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    fin.close();
    if (x != NULL) {
        delete[]x;
        x = new student[k];
    }
    if (x == NULL) { cout << "Нет памяти\n"; k = 0; return;}
    fin.open(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        fin >> x[i].name >> iniz >> x[i].dr.a >> x[i].dr.b >> x[i].dr.c;
        strcat(x[i].name, " ");
        strcat(x[i].name, iniz);
    }
    cout << "Файл введен.\n";
```

В файле 20 записей по типу:

- Yafec D.S 1 4 1998
- Yaungad N.N 5 9 2002
- Malikov V.M 3 5 2001

Comment: а как выглядит класс student?

Comment: struct student  
    {  
     char name[L];  
     date dr;  
    };  класс дата -  struct date  
    {  
     int a, b, c;  
    };

Comment: потому что код непонятный и результат должен быть непонятный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что функция обращалась к массиву x но не возвращала его проблема решена добавкой символа&: `void inputStudfile(student *&x, int &k)`